# GCM no workin on Lenovo

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello i have very weird problem, on my cheap phone all workingk fine, on nexus also all working fine, but on Lenovo GCM stopping working after registration. Log:

```
02-26 17:31:23.547 26309-26309/theinvaders.metoyou D/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service: CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@434a3900 className=theinvaders.metoyou.services.GcmRegistrationIntentService packageName=theinvaders.metoyou intent=null}
02-26 17:31:23.550 26309-26553/theinvaders.metoyou D/dalvikvm: threadid=27 (IntentService[GcmRegIntentService]): calling run()
02-26 17:31:23.559 26309-26309/theinvaders.metoyou D/ActivityThread: SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@434a3900 className=theinvaders.metoyou.services.GcmRegistrationIntentService packageName=theinvaders.metoyou intent=null}
02-26 17:31:23.559 26309-26309/theinvaders.metoyou D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: theinvaders.metoyou.services.GcmRegistrationIntentService@42886400, flags=0, startId=1
02-26 17:31:23.560 26309-26309/theinvaders.metoyou D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@434a3900 startId=1 args=Intent { cmp=theinvaders.metoyou/.services.GcmRegistrationIntentService }}
02-26 17:31:23.579 26309-26553/theinvaders.metoyou I/GcmRegIntentService: GCM Registration Token: fSc5ZhLmZ5Y:APA91bGq8klae_C6TEl4yjWJ6WAIQmW4A5pdor5fhhTq2i57Sfl3w7DPtkjaj3vZKdvadA5k9LVyVDpvENnqkKMvXu37jSHTHel4gzgOW6q_qUhQhzfNpXsZU1IirUYeMIEifpjljj8q
02-26 17:31:23.582 26309-26553/theinvaders.metoyou D/GCM: Registration Complete
02-26 17:31:23.713 26309-26309/theinvaders.metoyou I/GCM TOKEN: OK
02-26 17:31:23.713 26309-26309/theinvaders.metoyou D/ActivityThread: SVC-Destroying service: theinvaders.metoyou.services.GcmRegistrationIntentService@42886400
```

Perhaps anti-virus somehow blocks GCM?

Comment: Same issue here, only on Lenovo devices.

Comment: @Pawan I resolve this problem by adding multidex, and you also can remove subscribe by topics. Also GCM is deprecated now, use FCM instead. About multidex: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: Ok bro, will try. Thanks. (y)